# Are there any rules on what can be shown in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have an application in which one of the modules consists of a UIWebView in which articles are shown as HTML pages.

The problem is the articles could contain basically any outside link to images, videos other articles (from other providers), even adult content. In short it can contain links to unmoderated content.

Is it safe to open these links in the the applications UIWebView or are there some rules on what can be loaded in an applications? Should I just not open those links in the application and just open it with safari?

Comment: you can open in both UIWebView & Safari

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. You are responsible for what content is shown in your app. Failing to do so will get your app removed from appstore. You need to have a full reporting and abuse system implemented, and you need to be able to handle those incoming reports from your users. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ **1.2 User Generated Content**